# How to simplify (alternative way of writing) SQL query that uses Lead and Partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to understand and write the below query in a different way that has case statements with lead and partition by. I would really appreciate if any inputs on this.

```sql
SELECT CLIENT_ID,
       CASE
            WHEN GROUP_NM = LEAD(GROUP_NM, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID ORDER BY CLIENT_ID, START_DT)
             AND SNP_CD = LEAD(SNP_CD, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID ORDER BY CLIENT_ID, START_DT)
             AND DATEDIFF(DAY, END_DT, LEAD(START_DT, 1, CAST('19000101' AS date)) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID ORDER BY CLIENT_ID, START_DT)) = 1 THEN LEAD(END_DT, 1, CAST('19000101' AS date)) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID ORDER BY CLIENT_ID, START_DT)
            ELSE END_DT
       END AS END_DT,
       CASE
            WHEN GROUP_NM = LEAD(GROUP_NM, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID ORDER BY CLIENT_ID, START_DT)
             AND SNP_CD = LEAD(SNP_CD, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID ORDER BY CLIENT_ID, START_DT)
             AND DATEDIFF(DAY, END_DT, LEAD(START_DT, 1, CAST('19000101' AS date)) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID ORDER BY CLIENT_ID, START_DT)) = 1 THEN LEAD(DSNP_CODE, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID ORDER BY CLIENT_ID, START_DT)
            ELSE DSNP_CODE
       END AS DSNP_CODE
FROM dbo.HR;
```

Sample INPUT

[image]

Desired OUTPUT

[image]

So I think the lead function in sql server eliminates the need to join the same table to compare the values based on partition by column and set an output value. In this case the case statement probably grabs the latest end date and latest dsnp_code by comparing the group name with the next group name and snp_cd with the next snp_cd for a given client id and also check if the difference is one day between first record end date and second record start date.

Expecting the output as
[image]

Comment: What are you actually asking here, as it's not clear. IS the code you have not giving you the results you want? We can't run your code as we can't use your data, as it's an image; images of text aren't consumable as we can't copy that image and get text from it to use in our own environments. See [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: "...So I think the lead function in sql server eliminates the need to join the same table..." -- Yes. Prior to 2003 there was no `LAG()` or `LEAD()` analytical functions, so the solution before that time was to just join the table with itself and get the previous row using some quirky logic.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Sorry for the screenshots as this is the first attempt. I am looking to rewrite the above query that had lead and partition by without lead and partition by. Can we achieve /rewrite the same logic in a different way?